# What things should be taken point if we have to use unknown user css file

Tags: php, css, upload

I am thinking to let the users upload a css file and control the colour scheme and other things of the site as per their own configuration.

So before building it i would like to know what things i should take care?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the file once uploaded? Show it in a grid-like style?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css injection, what's the worst that can happen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718611/css-injection-whats-the-worst-that-can-happen)

Comment: If the CSS is for the consumption of the user that sets it *only*, then there's no problem. If they're shared... see the link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CSS injection is nearly as good as script injection. You've got `expression()` in IE6-7 (and later in compatibility view), you've got `behavior:` (HTC) in IE, you've got `-moz-binding:` in Firefox, you've got `content:` to inject text, and occasionally, mostly in older browsers that don't block it, you've got `url(javascript:...)`. Even without these you've got a fair amount of risk just from visual UI spoofing.

As long as a user stylesheet is limited to the user that made it, a user can only compromise themselves. The problem comes when users start sharing stylesheets. You might perhaps disallow users from picking the same external stylesheet address as another user to discourage this.

Answer (score 2):

Security: The so-called "[CSS Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" allow JavaScript code in CSS. Although they are now deprecated, they still work in IE5-7, and in IE's compatibility modes.

I recommend stripping out any `expression()` rule from the stylesheet. It serves no real purpose, doesn't work in normal browsers and in IE it introduces executable code to CSS.