# Is a cross-domain attack via stylesheet possible?

Tags: css, security, xss

I need to implement a flexible styling system for web pages that are created by users of my web application.

Ideally I would like to allow them to use CSS. Is linking to a style sheet at a user defined url a **Bad Idea**? *Why*? Is it possible to do this safely?

What would your approach to this be? I am trying to avoid building a style 'editor'. Though using an off the shelf one might be an option, suggestions?

Comment: I have just done such a system. I haven't used css-files, I have realized it completely database driven. It works very good out for me.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to do this safely?

Depends on how you define "safely". An external style sheet could make things look ugly, or play shenanigans with existing control elements on the site. You won't be able to prevent that as it's going to be impossible to detect. [Here](http://i8jesus.com/?p=10) is a nice overview of malicious things one can do that way.

Also, obviously, CSS can trigger requests to any kind of URL by setting a `background-image` or similar. The browser will notice if the URL is not a valid image resource but the request will always happen. This way, one could provoke a password prompt to come up that the site's user may mistake for his own login prompt.

I'm not aware of any *scripting* attack vectors through CSS, although I'm pretty sure that [IE's `behavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could be one. I would definitely strip out those.

There is a [related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718611/css-injection-whats-the-worst-that-can-happen) but none of the vulnerabilities pointed out in the accepted answer works with pure external style sheets.

Comment: you are correct sir, i've seen demos using behavior to generate dynamic styles, so why not scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  It can be a vector.  This bit [livejournal](http://www.auditmypc.com/network-security-12302005.asp).

> LiveJournal contains a flaw that allows a remote cross site scripting attack. This flaw exists because the application **does not validate CSS style attributes** in the `'/cgi-bin/cleanhtml.pl'` script before being saved. This could allow a user to create a specially crafted URL that would execute arbitrary code in a user's browser within the trust relationship between the browser and the server, leading to a loss of integrity. Read more at osvdb.org/21896

[Caja's Attack Vectors Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CssAllowsArbitraryCodeExecution) explains how `expression` and `moz-binding` and similar mechanisms can allow arbitrary code execution.

> #### Effect
>
> Crafted CSS stylesheets can execute unsanitized javascript in the global scope on some browsers.
>
> ...
>
> #### Versions
>
> IE 5 and later (but not IE 8 or later in "standards mode").
>
> Mozilla/Firefox, versions not known.
>
> #### Example
>
> ```
> <div id='oDiv' style='left:expression(alert("hello"), 0)'>
>   Example DIV
> </div>
>
> node.style.cssText = 'left:expression(alert("hello"), 0)';
>
> <input style='-moz-binding: url("http://www.mozilla.org/xbl/htmlBindings.xml#checkbox");'>
>
> div {
>   -moz-binding: url(data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cbindings%20id%3D%22xbltestBindings%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.mozilla.org/xbl%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cbinding%20id%3D%22xbltest%22%3E%3Ccontent%3EPASS%3C/content%3E%3C/binding%3E%0A%3C/bindings%3E%0A);
> }
> node.style.MozBinding = 'url("http://www.mozilla.org/xbl/htmlBindings.xml#checkbox")';
> <ul>
>   <li style="behavior:url(a1.htc) url(a2.htc)">List Item</li>
> </ul>
> ```

---

> Is it possible to do this safely?

Yes.  You can white-list CSS properties and strip out any you don't judge to be safe.

Caja defines [white-lists](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CajaWhitelists) in JSON format that allow a large subset of CSS to be used while banning those that might execute code.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about good old CSS expressions. Luckily, they will be a thing of the past when IE7 dies out... in 2035 or something. `mozBinding` looks interesting, although I don't fully understand how it works yet!

Comment: @Pekka: MS is re-releasing IE7 as "IE classic" in 2035 ;)

Comment: @Madmartigan, with an easter-egg that embeds IE6 as a trusted by default ActiveX control for extra hipster appeal.