# Angular: How to dynamically set colors to elements using a color input and save them to a database

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to set CSS colors and styles that is fetched from an API endpoint to HTML elements.

I have been able to achieve this but I feel it is not the best practice.

This is what I have. Any suggestion to achieve this in a more professional way?

my `.ts` file:

```
getColors(){
    this.api.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/colors").subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.colors = res.color
      console.log(res)
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--primary", this.colors)
    })
  }
```

and `.html` file:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="headerdiv">
        <h1>Welcome to Overflow</h1>
    </div>
</header>



<style>
    .header{
        background-color: var(--primary);
    }
    h3, h1{
        color: var(--h3color);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not inject CSS or any code via endpoint.

Loading CSS is problamtic. You are making you app very vunarable to code injection.

See Topics like
[CSS injection: what's the worst that can happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718611/css-injection-whats-the-worst-that-can-happen)

I suggest rethink you approach and load the color from inside the app.
Like getting a id from the api which translates to a color. In that way you can control the color from outside without injection potential malicious code.

Comment: Unless and until the end point is secured, the above approach looks fine.